# Is creating different objects with one POST call recommended with RestAPI

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm working on implementing a RESTfull API for my web application and it's in php. I have faced a problem on deciding whether it's recommended to create multiple different type of objects using single POST call is allowed. My scenario is as follows.

1. addEmployee api service function allow clients to create an employee inside my application by passing the data as POST parameters.
2. There are two dependencies for Employee in my system as Job Title and Employment Status and those are separately saved objects within the system. So client has to pass Job Title name and Employment Status name along with the addEmployee POST call.
3. When a client calls addEmployee method, it internally checks whether given Job Title and Employment Status are already there in the system and if so it only add a reference for those existing objects within the Employee object.
4. **If given Job Title or Employment Status is not there in the system, addEmployee method will first save Job Title and Employment Status objects in the system and then will add a references in the Employee Object.**
5. There are separate API functions for addJobTitle and addEmploymentStatus which can be used by client if they need to add more Job Titles and Employment Statuses to the system.

In the above workflow I'm not sure whether 4th step is correct because the internal saving operation is not visible to client and it reduce the visibility of the API. But usability wise it's good because client can add an Employee with maximum one web service call.

I can replace the 4th step as follows to improve the visibility.

4. **If given Job Title or Employment Status are not there in the system, addEmployee method will return an exception saying those are not available in the system and along with that response will provide uris to addJobTitle and addEmploymentStatus functions allowing clients to use uris and save those Job Titles and Employment Status first. After saving Job Title and Employment Status objects client can again call addEmployee method to add the employee with given Job Title and Employment Status.**

2nd approach will improve the visibility of the API but performance vise and usability vise it will not be much effective because client has to call API 3 times maximum to add an Employee to the system.

Please advice me what is the approach I should follow to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 4th step you are attempting is valid without any changes and also is the recommended approach.

- If you consider Job Title and Employment Status, both of them are related to the Employee
- The best approach is that you don't expose methods in your API to add Job Title and add Employment Status. Because if you do the client can keep on creating those for example one can create Job Title `Software Engineer` and another can create `SW Engineer`. Before you know it you have hundreds of Job Titles. Same applies to Employment Status.
- Only Listing methods for Job Title and Employment Status may suffice with backend provisioning of those (SQL or Manual Insert or Admin only insert)
- Finally as you mentioned you can reduce the multiple calls and reduce bandwidth which is crucial if the API is to be used by for example Mobile Apps over Wireless Networks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer for @shazin. I will be waiting little bit more time to check whether anyone else is answering for this. After that I'll proceed with marking the answer as the correct answer.

Anyway do you know any reference API I can look into which is 100% RESTful. Does companies follows 100% RESTful web services or it's just a concept which is compromised in the real world implementations due to various other factors.